# Setting volume level of mix

Tags: mixing, mastering, sound-design, volume

From what level of decibels should I start to set the volume of tracks in the mix? 
I've heard that usually it starts at **-6dB on a kick** and match the rest of track's volume to that kick ...

Is it right way?

Comment: I used to think that it's forbidden to exceed 0dB... Are u sure that +6dB or even 4dB are ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix with your eyes, boss!!! If it sounds good don't touch anything else to make it 'look' good... music is not seen (literally), it's heard. So, start with the kick (or loudest thing on set), make sure it's loud enough and that it doesn't distort, and work from that point of reference on. But, please, don't change levels because it is not visually appealing- I met engineers that mix with their eyes and struggle with consoles with no meters! Good luck!